# how do I set up factory_girl in my test_helper.rb file to use with shoulda?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shoulda, mailer, factory-bot

I have the following:

```
  1 ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
  2 require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../config/environment")
  3 require 'test_help'
  4 require 'shoulda'
  5 require 'factory_girl'
  6 FactoryGirl.find_definitions
```

I get an error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant OutboundEmail
```

I put it there because when I ran my test without it, it didn't recognize my OutboundMailer:

```
require 'test_helper'
  2 
  3 class OutboundMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase
  4 
  5   context "test creating email" do
  6 
  7     setup do
  8       @email = Factory.build(:outbound_email) #create email from factory
  9     end
 10 
 11     should "test sending of the outbound email" do
 12       @expected.subject = "#{@email.subject}"
 13       @expected.body    = "#{@email.body}"
 14       @expected.date    = Time.now
 15 
 16       assert_equal @expected.encoded, OutboundMailer.create_email(@expected.date).encoded
 17     end
 18   end
 19 end
```

Comment: Rails 2.3.x, or Rails 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo. You should use

```
Factory.find_definitions
```

not

```
FactoryGirl.find_definitions
```

As you do in your OutboundMailerTest class.